# Cancel Navigation in TabbarRenderer Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer

I have a custom tabbar renderer for iOS in a `Xamarin.Forms` app. In certain cases, I need to stop the `ItemSelected` event. Essentially, if the user taps the item on the tabbar, I need to perform a custom action and NOT navigate.

It seems that the `ItemSelectedevent` is too late to do this. I know that there is a `ShouldShowViewController` method on the `UITabbarController`, but this has been abstracted away by the `TabbarRenderer`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hey,did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

There is a method `SelectViewController` .It return a bool value .If return `True`,it will navigate a new page when you select the item ,and won't if return false.You can refer the following code.(For example you don't want to navigate when you click the second child page on tabbed page )

> in Custom Renderer

```
private xxx page;//xxx is your tabbedPage in forms

protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnElementChanged(e);

  if(e.NewElement!=null)
  {
    page = (xxx)e.NewElement;
  }

  else
  {
    page = (xxx)e.OldElement;
  }

  if (this.Element != null)
  {
     UITabBarController tabbar = (UITabBarController)this.ViewController;

     tabbar.ShouldSelectViewController += SelectViewController;

  }

}


public  bool SelectViewController(UITabBarController tabBarController, UIViewController viewController)
{
  if(viewController==this.ViewControllers[1])
  {
    //do something you want 

    return false;
  }

  else
  {
    return true;
  }

}
```